# How to get Body from API using uWebSocket.js?

Tags: node.js, uwebsockets

I'm using **uWebSocket.js** and tried to get the payload from an API. I have checked [its official GitHub site related to routes](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets.js/blob/master/examples/Router.js).

I checked and implemented all the way explained in that and it works fine. However, I'm facing issue to fetch the **body data from post method**.

What I tried is...

```
let app = uWS
    ./*SSL*/App()
    .post('/login', (res, req) => {
        console.log(req.body); 
        res.end(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Nothing to see here!' }));
    })
    .ws('/*', {
        /* Options */
        compression: uWS.SHARED_COMPRESSOR,
        maxPayloadLength: 16 * 1024 * 1024,
        idleTimeout: 10 * 4,
        maxBackpressure: 1024,
        open: (ws) => {
            /* Let this client listen to topic "broadcast" */
            
        },
        message: (ws, message, isBinary) => {
            
        },
        drain: (ws) => { },
        close: (ws, code, message) => {
            
        }
    })
    .listen(port, (token) => {
        if (token) {
            console.log('Listening to port ' + port);
        } else {
            console.log('Failed to listen to port ' + port);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the res.data method as mentioned here https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets/issues/805#issuecomment-451800768

Here is an example

```
.post("/short", (res, req) => {
  res
    .onData((data) => {
      const stringed = handleArrayBuffer(data);
      console.log("stringed received", stringed);
    })
    res.write("Great knowing you");
    res.writeStatus("200OK");
    res.end();
})
```

The data received above will come in as an array buffer so you will probably want to decode it to a string like this

```
export const handleArrayBuffer = (message: ArrayBuffer | string) => {
  if (message instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
    const decoder = new TextDecoder();
    return decoder.decode(message);
  }
  return message;
};
```